# Center Fontastic Fonts, which are A tags?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a footer in my website where I use some Fontastic fonts as social icons. The fonts are displayed using `a` tags. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to center these tags within the div. If it helps, I am using Foundation 5 framework with Sass. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<footer>
  <div id="social"class="row">
    <div class="large-3 small-3 small-centered columns">
      <a href="#" class="icon-gplus"></a>
      <a href="#" class="icon-circled"></a>
      <a href="#" class="icon-twitter"></a>
      <a href="#" class="icon-linkedin"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#social {
    background: $grey-color;
    p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 24px;
    }
}
.small-centered {
    margin-top: 36px;
}
.icon-gplus {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: $dark-grey-color;
    text-align: center;
    &:hover{
        color: $black;
    }
}
.icon-circled {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: $dark-grey-color;
    text-align: center;
    &:hover{
        color: $black;
    }
}
.icon-twitter {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: $dark-grey-color;
    text-align: center;
    &:hover{
        color: $black;  
    }
}
.icon-linkedin {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: $dark-grey-color;
    text-align: center;
    &:hover{
        color: $black;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `text-align:center` on the container to center your icons. Right now you're apply `text-align: center` to `#social p`, which does not exist.

```
.small-centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I am using the `#social p` to align the text in a `div` that I have underneath the div that I posted - that is the reason for it. I tried the use the solution that you posted but it did not work. I appreciate your input.

Comment: Can you put your code up on jsfiddle? Or provide a link to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is working:

CSS (Sass)

```
#social {
    background: $grey-color;
    p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 24px;
    }
}
.small-centered {
    margin-top: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon-gplus {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: $dark-grey-color;
    text-align: center;
    @include color-transition(.35s);
    &:hover{
        color: $black;
    }
}
.icon-circled {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: $dark-grey-color;
    text-align: center;
    @include color-transition(.35s);
    &:hover{
        color: $black;
    }
}
.icon-twitter {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: $dark-grey-color;
    text-align: center;
    @include color-transition(.35s);
    &:hover{
        color: $black;  
    }
}
.icon-linkedin {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: $dark-grey-color;
    text-align: center;
    @include color-transition(.35s);
    &:hover{
        color: $black;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<footer>
      <div id="social"class="row">
        <div class="large-3 small-3 small-centered columns">
          <a href="#" class="icon-gplus"></a>
          <a href="#" class="icon-circled"></a>
          <a href="#" class="icon-twitter"></a>
          <a href="#" class="icon-linkedin"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="social" class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <p>&copy;Blah | Graphic Design | Web Designer | </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```